# What operation is used to construct single image of dual-energy x-ray scanned object?

Tags: x-rays, image-processing

I know that for dual-energy x-ray screening, two different energies are used which produces two distinct images. I want to know how these images are combined to result in a single image. I know that this resulting image is further more processed to show different colors for different materials.

Answer (score 0):

Is this about energies just below and just above an absorption edge of for example iodine? A simple difference image (grayscale) will then show where the contrast image is (arteries in a coronography for example).

One could use color to visualize both density and the difference in density. This requires more expertise about how to visualize information intuitively.